# pyqt5: execute a local function for evaluation by accessing the values entered in GUI widgets

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am developing a GUI with some drop downs and Line-edit fields. I can get it working. The scenario is that, with the entered values(all on button presses or keyboard typing), I want to evaluate these values and then activate the 'execute tool' button in GUI.

The problem is that I have no button or any interrupt for this evaluate function. It should be done automatically after all fields are filled.

I have a separate function for evaluation. But I am not knowing how to call this simple python 'evaluation' function in between GUI process.

[image: Similar sample image]

```
    class ApplicationWindow:
        def __init__(self):
          ### .... init variables
    
        def main_gui(self):
        # creating a qt gui widget application Object to display - Config setup
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        ... # All basic stuff for GUI setup, init & connect on key press
        self.gui.i_year_num.activated.connect(lambda: self.i_year_fun())
        self.gui.i_month_num.activated.connect(lambda: self.i_month_fun())
        # self.evaluate()       # Calling here executes this fun before even GUI is opened
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
        
        def evaluate(self):
            if ((self.i_year is not None)
                    and (self.i_month is not None) and .... #conditions# ):
                print("All fields are not empty")
                self.i_flag = True
    
            if ((self.i_year == '')
                    or (self.i_month == '') or .... #conditions#):
                self.showInfoDialog('Error', ' All fields should be filled! ')
    
            self.file_name_tag = str(self.i_name) + '-' + str(self.i_year) + '-' \
                                 + str(self.i_month) + '-' + str(self.version_id)
            print("Name tag is ", self.file_name_tag)


# The gui is called here
ApplicationWindow_object = ApplicationWindow()
ApplicationWindow_object.main_gui()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks. I hope it's clear enough with image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a method that validates all the inputs and invoke it every time something changes in the inputs you want to monitor:

```
    self.gui.button.setEnabled(False)
    # connections
    self.gui.i_year_num.activated.connect(self.verify_validate)
    self.gui.i_month_num.activated.connect(self.verify_validate)

def verify_validate(self):
    is_valid = self.validate()
    self.gui.button.setEnabled(is_valid)
    if not is_valid:
        self.showInfoDialog('Error', ' All fields should be filled! ')


def validate(self):
    if not all(self.gui.i_year_num, self.gui.i_month):
        # some input is empty
        return False
    # other checks
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I do not want a button for this validation. I want my script to do it automatically after they are entered. That is my actual problem.

Comment: @Priya That's what my solution does: Validate all entries every time the user modifies them. Have you tested my solution?

Comment: I already have specific funtions to be called on every activation. For ex : self.gui.i_year_num.activated.connect(lambda: self.i_year_fun()), how do I also call  self.verify_validate function? Another solution would be to add the logic of evaluation in all functions that are connected. (which is very redundant)